# Pandas read_csv PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Where/How can I grant permission for Pandas to read_csv in Jupyter Notebook?

**Here's what I'm running:**

```
import pandas as pd
from summarizer import Summarizer

df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/inputdata.csv')
```

**Here's the error I'm getting:**

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
> '/Users/[user_name]/Desktop/inputdata.csv'

> PermissionError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> /var/folders/3v/m603r7n912x5s5__z9z3_9pc0000gp/T/ipykernel_53047/717928769.py
> in <module

**I found this part:**

/var/folders/3v/m603r7n912x5s5__z9z3_9pc0000gp/T

**But this doesn't exist:**

/ipykernel_53047/717928769.py

I assume this matters, but don't know why nor what to do with it.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the path you saved your datasets. You can change the address and save it in a new address may solve the issue because the path you saved is your System PATH and needs permission to use.

Comment: Wow, that did it! Thanks, @Raha. For the record, I placed it in /Frameworks/Python.framework file, which asked me to enter my system password when I tried to drop the .csv in. Maybe that was the permission needed. Still don't know - but really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have the same issue with jupyternotebook and .csv file saved in drive